# Is it possible to preset the type of a new selection in the jQuery FormBuilder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, formbuilder

I use the nice FormBuilder from Kevin Chappell

https://formbuilder.online/docs/

Several types can be defined for the 'text' field. I have integrated the new control 'time'. I now want if this new control is clicked, 'time' should be preset in the 'Type' field.

How can i adjust that?

PS: The code example does not run here but only locally (sessionStorage topic)

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var fbTemplate = document.getElementById('fb-editor');
  var options = {
    fields : [{
        label: 'Time',
        attrs: {
            type: 'text'
        },
        icon: ''
    }],
    subtypes: {
      text: ['datetime-local','time']
    },
    disabledSubtypes: {
        text: ['password','email','color','tel'],
    }
  };
  $(fbTemplate).formBuilder(options);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - formBuilder: Options -&gt; subtypes</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div id="fb-editor"></div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://formbuilder.online/assets/js/form-builder.min.js'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find out, but i took a different path for it. :-)

Enter the new element as type `time` in the `field` definition.
A new `subtype` `time` has also been defined.

Then add the `time` in the `controls register`.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var fbTemplate = document.getElementById('fb-editor');
  var options = {
    fields : [{
      label: 'Time',
      attrs: {
        type: 'time'
      },
      icon: ''
    }],
    subtypes: {
      time: ['time']
    }
  };
  $(fbTemplate).formBuilder(options);
});

// src/js/control/text.js
// register this control for the following types & text subtypes
control.register(['text', 'file', 'date', 'number', 'time'], controlText)
control.register(['text', 'password', 'email', 'color', 'tel'], controlText, 'text')
```

```css
body {
  background: lightgrey;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>formBuilder</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="fb-editor"></div>

<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://formbuilder.online/assets/js/form-builder.min.js'></script>
<script  src="./script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```